# Word by Word UILabel animation from left to right in swift

Tags: swift, animation, uilabel

I have a uilabel with a text suppose " This is a label." I want this label to be displayed one word at a time flying from outside screen to the UILable position..
something like
label.
a label.
is a label.
This is a label.

How can i get such animation

Answer (score 1):

I have found a way to do as i wished.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var sampleLabel: UILabel!


var slogan = "This is a slogan."
var xdir = 250

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)


    let sampleLabelFrame = sampleLabel.frame
    let ypos = sampleLabelFrame.origin.y
    var sloganArray = slogan.componentsSeparatedByString(" ")
    sloganArray = sloganArray.reverse()
    var i = 0.0
    for word in sloganArray{
        let label: UILabel = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: -100, y:ypos, width: 60, height: 20))
        label.text = word
        view.addSubview(label)


        let width = label.intrinsicContentSize().width
        var labelFramewidth = label.frame
        labelFramewidth.size.width = width
        label.frame = labelFramewidth
        self.xdir = self.xdir - Int(width)-4

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.7, delay: i, options: .CurveEaseOut, animations: {
            var labelframe = label.frame
            labelframe.origin.x = CGFloat(self.xdir)



            label.frame = labelframe
            }, completion: { finished in


        })

        i+=0.5
    }

}


}
```

hope this helps others in need of something like this.

Comment: Thanks - I was looking for something like this. Turned out to be not exactly what I needed though but I took the chance to update your code to Swift 4 and edited your answer. Edit is now in review so it might show soon under your solution.

Answer (score -1):

This might help you on the way to achieve what you want:

http://helpmecodeswift.com/animation/creating-animated-labels

EDIT:

Flying label code:

```
    meme1.text = "Brace yourself!"
    meme1.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(25)
    meme1.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()      // This is all just styling the Label
    meme1.sizeToFit()
    meme1.center = CGPoint(x: 200, y: -50)    // Starting position of the label

    view.addSubview(meme1)  // Important! Adding the Label to the Subview, so we can actually see it.

    //Animation options. Play  around with it.
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.9, delay: 0.0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.3, initialSpringVelocity: 0.0, options: .CurveLinear, animations: {

        self.meme1.center = CGPoint(x: 200, y:50 )  // Ending position of the Label

        }, completion: nil)


    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.6, delay: 1.1, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.3, initialSpringVelocity: 0.0, options: .CurveLinear, animations: {

        self.meme1.center = CGPoint(x: 200, y:150+90 )



        }, completion: nil)
```

I have no experience with it myself, but it seems to get your job done. You can eventually se the starting point outside the screen and let it animate over to the screen. That should give the desired effect.